# Randomly Channel.Connect.Failed error when calling to a Java server from Flex application using AMF protocol

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, amf

I have a project published in the Internet that is used by thousands of users every day. Basically, I'm using a server in AmazonAWS with the server part compiled in Java 6 running in a Tomcat. I'm using AMF to publish the services and my client is built in Flex 4.6 using Flash Builder to generate the classes to connect to the AMF services. The code I'm using to connect to the services is this:

```
    public var cpcService:RemotingServicesImpl;

    private function callService():void
    {
        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.callingService=true;

        encryptedSession=ResourcesUtil.buildSessionId(globalSettings.sessionId, globalSettings);
        var responder:Responder=new Responder(gameStateLoaded, gameStateFailed);
        var token:AsyncToken=cpcService.getGameState(encryptedSession, taskKey);
        token.addResponder(responder);
    }

    private function gameStateFailed(ev:FaultEvent=null):void
    {
        DisplayUtil.trackErrorInfoEvent("FATAL - FatalError", "getGameState-" + FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.mainView.currentState, ev, encryptedSession);
    }

    private function gameStateLoaded(ev:Object):void
    {
        // my fantastic code when everything is ok
    }
```

Normally, everything is ok and my application is working, but some calls (like 1 every 500) are not working, I know it because in the trackErrorInfoEvent function I'm registering an event in the Google Analytics, so I know this is randomly happening. This is the error:

```
faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'https://appcog.cognifit.com/messagebroker/amf'"
faultString = "Send failed"
rootCause = (null)
```

Of course the URL is correct and is working all times.

I have seen in [some blogs](http://www.reynacho.com/2009/02/flex-channelconnectfailed-error-netconnectioncallfailed-http-status-200/) that adding this line:

```
    <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
```

the problem is fixed, but I have that line in my config file and is still happening.

I have checked my server logs and I have no records for service interruptions at any time.

I really apreciate any help, thanks in advance!